# Convert MySql Database to C# LocalDB

Tags: mysql, transfer, localdb

Is there any way that can convert or transfer a MySql Server Based Database to LocalDB in C#?
Actually, my application connects to MySql Server Based Database through Localhost.
(i made the database in MySql Workbench 5.2 CE)
What i want is to take every table in this database and add it to a new LocalDB in C# but i don't 
want to make this manually(e.g create new table, add columns, save it and so on..)

Sorry if u find it difficult to understand what i want, i just don't know how to explain it
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a way to do this by using [this](http://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/howto/mysql-to-sqlce) program. Its a "30 days trial" but i think it worths
to buy it. Amazing program:p